# Is there a function in woocommerce to create programmatically a category for a product?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to attach a category to a product and create that category if it does not exist. There is my code. The issue is that the wp_insert function can't read the variable i passed

```
$products = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'label' => 'tecno xyz',
    'price' => 1250 ,
    'category' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'label' => 'high tech')
     );
$category = $products['category']['label'];

$testCateg = is_product_category([$term = $category]);
if (!$testCateg) {
    wp_insert_term(
      $category, // the term 
      'product_cat', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'description'=> 'New New Category description for testing purpose'
        //'slug' => 'new-category'
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey @Essy Telle! What do you mean that the `wp_insert_term` function can't read the variable you have passed? In your example, `$category` will be set to `high tech`. Do you mean that a new category doesn't get created? Also, as far as I know, `is_product_category` only checks if you are on a certain product category page (see [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) for a list of tags available on each page). Instead, you might need to use `get_terms` (or similar) to get existing product categories.

Comment: Yes @DiegoColantoni, the category is not created. the is_product_category return a bool weither the category exists or not. I have tested it by writting my categry as a plain string, not a variable

Comment: Doesn't the `is_product_category` function only return true if you are on the corresponding product category page? If you are sure that the `wp_insert_term` gets invoked (i.e. the `$testCateg` is false), have you checked if a `WP_Error` object is returned by the function?

Comment: the is_product_category does not work as well, because of the variable i passed to it. The name of the category is write in plain string, everything is ok!

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, `wp_insert_term( 'high tech', 'product_cat' )` works, but it doesn't when using the `$category` variable. There must be something else going on (e.g. `$category` is never set). Would you be able to post the complete code?

Comment: I have printed $category to ensure it contains something and it does, but, when passing it to the function, it does not work. It is the complete code. I am trying to upload products from a different location to woocommerce, so i would like to test if i can set the categories of those products programmatically

Comment: I've added an answer, hopefully it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a product category exists, don't use `is_product_category`, as that function is used to check if a certain product category page is displayed (see [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) for a list of tags available on each page).

Product category is a custom taxonomy (`product_cat`) used by WooCommerce, so the existing product categories can be retrieved simply using `get_terms`. For example, adding a new category if it doesn't already exist can be achieved like this:

```
function add_product_category() {
  $new_product = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'label' => 'tecno xyz',
    'price' => 1250,
    'category' => array(
      'id' => 1,
      'label' => 'high tech',
    ),
  );
  $category = $new_product['category']['label'];
  $args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
  );
  $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
  foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $product_category ) {
    if ( $product_category->name === $category ) {
      return;
    }
  }
  $term = wp_insert_term(
    $category,
    'product_cat',
    array(
      'description' => 'New Category description for testing purpose',
    ),
  );
  if ( is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
    // do something with error.
  }
}
```